# Check in react component if a styleName exists

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm planning to call the css selectors that I imported on my React component dynamically. 
But it is throwing an error if a style doesn't exist

`Uncaught Error: Could not resolve the styleName 'dynamicvalue3'.`

Is it possible in react to have a check like this `isClassExists('dynamicvalue3')`?

Example:
Here's my css file sample content. filename is `mycustomcss.styles.css`

```
.dynamicvalue1 {}
.dynamicvalue2 {background-color: #87c930;}
```

And on the render method of my react component is

```
import theme from './mycustomcss.styles.css';
.....
const badge = /* This will be fetch dynamically. And the values will vary from dynamicvalue1, dynamicvalue2 etc.. */;
.....
return (<div styleName={badge}>Text here</div>}/>);
```

Problem:
Since `dynamicvalue3` doesn't exist, it will throw an error. So i'm thinking if this approach is indeed possible.

Thanks

Comment: Hi! Can you add some code as example? It's quite hard to understand your question :) Anyways, if I've understood correctly, if you have the `ref` to the element which you want to check if it has the CSS class, you may want to see the `Element.classList` method: https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: @Jolly, I added example now, hope it's clearer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check it like like this `theme.dynamicvalue3` it will return a truthy value if it exist

```
const badge = theme.dynamicvalue3 ? theme.dynamicvalue3 : theme.dynamicvalue2
```